# Is there a way to always retain last message in the topic in Kafka server?

Tags: apache-kafka

From official Kafka documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#gettingStarted there are time and size retention parameters. Is there a way to configure Kafka to always keep last message per topic regardless how long it would be?
Currently I am thinking to republish it at the end of expiration period, that does not look like good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such functionality. I would also like to have a functionality like this, as it is a use case for me. A way to keep the topic small is to use log compaction and not setting retention parameters. See: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the section of log compaction and having a topic setting of `cleanup.policy=compact` will keep messages retained indefinitely, but only those with unique keys.

Note that ***all*** messages will be retained within an open "segment", which defaults to 1GB worth of data, while any closed, old segments will have uniquely keyed events. You can tune the segment size and "dirty ratio" of a topic to make the `LogCleaner` more aggressive, but this comes at a performance cost.